# Загрузка данных с Firebase в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, kotlin, firebase

Я получаю изображение с БД Fibase и вывожу его через RecyclerView. Все нормально, но т.к. изображение не маленькое, идет загрузка, и смотреть на это не очень весело. 
Я придумал решение.
При старте активити я ставлю `recyclerView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE`.
Идет загрузка данных. Я их не вижу. Но в этот момент я создаю другой поток, в котором я ставлю паузу на 1 секунду и `recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE`.
В результате у меня после запуска ничего не видно в течении 1 секунды, затем сразу полностью заполненный recyclerView. Во время этой паузы можно поставить анимацию загрузки и все отлично.
Было бы идеально, если бы на этом конец. Но все это происходит во фрагменте, который можно переключать в Navigation Drawer. При запуске приложения все идет по плану, НО, если ОТКРЫТЬ эту же вкладку еще раз через боковое меню, то после паузы recyclerView не отображается. НО, если скролить, как будто там что-то есть, то recyclerView появится.
Я понимаю, что это способ не очень, но, если у Вас есть идея решить его, буду рад. Также, буду рад другим вариантам решения этой проблемы. Заранее спасибо.

itemClickListener

```
override fun onItemClick(view: View?, position: Int, drawerItem: IDrawerItem<*>): Boolean {

                if (result.drawerItems[position-1].isEnabled){
                    result.closeDrawer()
                    return true
                }

                var fragment: Fragment? = null
                when (position) {
                    1 -> {
                        fragment = TestFragment1()
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        fragment = TestFragment2()
                    }
                }

                doAsync {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000)
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                        fragmentTransaction.commit()
                    }
                }

                return false
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

1 в Drawere естественно проверять открыт фрагмент или нет. Если открыт то не сеттить повторно. Это же логично. Зачем по 30 раз загружать одмн и тот же фрагмент.
2 заюзать для подгрузки картинок что то типа Glide, и ставить progressBar в картинку и placeHolder снизу. Вот собственно и все без костылей.И не нужны никакие потоки и визибалы))))

Добавлю:

```
   @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    /*проверяем выбран ли пункт или еще нет , что бы не откывать повторно*/
    if (navigationView.getMenu().findItem(id).isChecked()) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    switch (id) {.......
```

Ну а картинку типа того, например `пикассо` в адаптере `onBindViewHolder`:

```
    try {
        Picasso.get()
                .load(url_image)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placehoder)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.image_news);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Picasso.get()
                .load(R.drawable.no_product)
                .into(holder.image_news);
    }
```

Comment: Завтра попробую, спасибо.)

Comment: С загрузкой изображения решил. Поставил белую полосу. И теперь текст под картинкой загружается не слева, а затем переноситься в центру, а в нем сразу, и вместо белой полосы изображение загружается за секунду. Хотелось, конечно, чтобы загрузка была без белых полос и т.п., но я думаю сделать потом сохранение текущего recyclerView в БД, и если изменений нет, то загрузка идет с неё. Думаю, будет быстрее. А проблема с выбором вкладок осталась, но она не критична. Если выбрать одну и ту же вкладку, то на 2ой раз долгой загрузки нет, наверное, т.к. Пикассо кеширует эти фото.

Comment: Проблема состоит в том, что это кастомный Drawer - (https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) . Этих стандартных методов `.getMenu()` и т.п. нет. Я искал аналогичные, но что-то в результате выходит не то. Я запретил повторное открытие вкладки, если она сейчас активна. Все хорошо, но если с 1 переключить на 2, и затем обратно на 1, то она не загружается. Там есть метод `.currentSelectedPosition`, который выдает мне позицию, но нет метода, который проверяет `isCheked()`.

Comment: А в чем проблема сравнивать с currentSelectPosition? Или я что то не так понял?

Comment: Как я понимаю `if (navigationView.getMenu().findItem(id).isChecked())` должен спрашивать, отмечена ли в меню вкладка под номером ID. Т.е., если активна 1 вкладка, и переключить на 2ую, то будет запрос, активна ли 2ая, если нет, то включить. У меня есть аналогичный запрос `if (result.drawerItems[position-1].isEnabled)`, но он всегда возвращает TRUE. И каждый аналогичный метод возвращает значение, как будто я уже переключил вкладку и только тогда спросил, а не наоборот. ДОБАВИЛ ВЕСЬ КОД В ПЕРВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ.